# R data table issue when using set for column updating

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to update some columns in a data table, using set seems to be an efficient solution:

```
dt <- data.table(mtcars)[,1:5, with=F]
for (j in c(1L,2L,4L)) set(dt, j=j, value=-dt[[j]])
```

The problem I have is if I run the above lines, I get:

```
Error in set(dt, j=j, value= -dt[[j]]) : unused argument (j=j)
```

Interestingly the above lines work just fine in a different machine, with same R and data.table version.

Has anyone faced a similar issue?

Comment: Can you post the `sessionInfo()` output from both machines?

Comment: maybe run `getAnywhere("set")`? and see if there are any other `set` function in the scoping namespaces

Comment: Was puzzled about this error, that even tried just re-starting my R session and worked, not sure what happened. Thanks